# Widening Hole in Cloth Sim

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am in the early stages of modelling a robe which has an existing neck hole at the top of it that is supposed to be a fixed size. I have set up a basic test to see how it will react when resting on an object and it seems to do a weird thing on collision where the neck hole widens until the whole robe eventually falls through the sphere I created.

Here are some images of what I'm talking about. These are the cloth and the collision settings:

[image: robe with the correct sized neck hole and cloth settings]

[image: sphere object with collision settings]

And here's the problem once it's animated:

[image: cloth collision with widening hole]

To be clear I just want the robe to rest on the sphere object and not fall through it. This also happens when I make the object it's colliding with different shapes such as cubes. Let me know if I can add anything to make it easier to help. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: I tried a similar setup and it doesn't happen, could you share your .blend (eg: here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: @m.ardito that's interesting. Here's the file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2108/

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is: bad topology of the cloth object...

here's your mesh topology:

[image]

And topology is all about good deformations...

I did a quick test of a "square" cloth object (not particularly good topology, but way better than your object...), just to check and, with default cloth / collision settings... is subdived and then also subssurfed...

animation starts like this:

[image]

and after 136 frames:

[image]

here is my test .blend
[image]

**update:**

here is a simpler test with higher "structural" setting...

[image]

Comment: thanks @m.ardito! I'll work on improving the topology of my mesh then. I've noticed with your file that although it is much improved and it stays on the sphere object, the hole does still expand on collision. Is that something that you think could be resolved by further improving the topology of the mesh?

Comment: I tried an even simpler example using way higher "structural" setting... see the edited answer...